# Qt-project as a git-submodule for another Qt-project

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a Qt-application. It has a `.pro` file with `TEMPLATE = app`. One of the project's subfolders is a git-submodule to another Qt project: a collection of libraries, which has it's own `.pro` file with `TEMPLATE = subdirs`.

Graphically it looks like:

```
project/
    app.pro (TEMPLATE = app)
    stuff/
    libs/ <-- git-submodule
        libs.pro (TEMPLATE = subdirs)
        lib1/
            lib1.pro (TEMPLATE = lib)
        lib2/
            lib2.pro (TEMPLATE = lib)
```

`libs` as a standalone project compiles well and produces `.lib` files.
But in this case I want somehow include `libs.pro` to a `project` as a subdir although `app.pro`'s `TEMPLATE` is not `subdirs` but `app`. Maybe that is why my attempts to write something like `SUBDIRS += askelib` to `app.pro` had no effect.
All in all my aim is to get `.lib` files inside build folder of `app.pro`.
I emphasize that `libs` is a git-submodule because nothing should be changed inside `libs` project to achieve my goal.

I know that it probably should work if I change `app.pro`'s `TEMPLATE` to `subdirs`. But that's not what I really want to do because it will make things more difficult since project hierarchy then will achieve another nesting level:

```
subdirs_proj/
    app/
    libs/
```

instead of

```
app/
    libs/
```

**EDIT:**
To clerify my reasons:

My aim is to make a project tree as clearer as it can be. Like you clone a project from github, enter into it's directory and see `app.pro` at the top level. And everything is clear, easy and beautiful. And not like you see a strange `subdirs.pro` at the top but the actual project is in `app` subdirectory and you also have posibility to confuse main application subfolder with a library subfolder in case if their names are not so obvious as `app` and `libs` but something like `torpedo` and `helios`. Hope my thought is clear :)

Comment: Possible to get a sample repo for this?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, sure, [this one](https://github.com/AskePit/Memory). Here I have `Memory.pro` at the top which is `subdirs`, library directory and `src` directory. Previously, before library usage there was no need in `src`directory and `Memory.pro` was an actual app's `pro` file. Which was more convenient for me

Comment: How about using environment variables here? You can use a environment variables and get the value like `TEMPLATE = $$(TEMPLATE_ENV)` and then if it is [empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803893/test-if-a-variable-is-empty-and-give-default-value-during-qmake), you can assign it a default value. Then during your main project build you can export that environment variable and let it override the value in a references library project? I am not a qmake expert, so some assumptions may be wrong but you could see if this makes any sense

Answer (score 8):

You already have your answer: make the top-level project a subdir project.

I do not understand why you want to avoid that and why you find it confusing.
IMHO, having an `app` project that has subdirs is more confusing than having a `subdir` project that has subdirs.

And I don't think removing a folder level compensate for having subdirs in an app `.pro`. Think about a new developer coming on the project, if he sees `TEMPLATE=app` he will assume you only build a single project, but it is not. Meaning that your project is not "clear, easy and beautiful" and completely violates the principle of least astonishment.

I regularly have projects that have the following architecture:

```
project-a/project-a.pro (subdirs)
         /cli-app/cli-app.pro (app)
         /gui-app/gui-app.pro (app)
         /core-lib/core-lib.pro (lib)
         /3rd-party/3rd-party.pro (subdirs)
         /3rd-party/somelib/somelib.pro (lib)
```

I find it clearer than messing with the project type to remove a folder level. And if you are afraid developers will not know what each sub folder is, maybe you should throw some README files explaining what is what.

Also you can take a look at the Qt project itself, it has many .pro files and not once you have an app project that contains subdirs. And I think it is rather clear, in particular for such a big project.